# Solaris 11 ldap client configuration

Tags: configuration, ldap, solaris, certificate, web-services

Im am trying to migrate some web services (like wordpress / dokuwiki), which are connected to our ldap for user authentication, from solaris 10 to solaris 11. In solaris 10, you had the possibility to configure the client not to request or check any server certificate. This was done via TLS_REQCERT never in the ldap config (/etc/opt/csw/openldap/ldap.conf).

Does anyone knows how to configure this in solaris 11? Or how to configure the client to use our certificates? I cant find any ldap configuration on our solaris 11 hosts, nor documentation how the certificates should be installed on the host to be used for ldap connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you described it looks like you were using an OpenLDAP client implementation instead of the Solaris 10 bundled LDAP client. So, you just have to download the same packages from OpenCSW as before and configure it the same way you did before. I am not sure, though, if OpenCSW supports Solaris 11 due to its new package format etc. etc.